# What are the popular modes-of-operation (AES-GCM, AES-SIV, AES-GCM-SIV, etc.) geared for?

Tags: aes, authenticated-encryption, modes-of-operation, gcm, aes-gcm

I'm interested in developing software capable of encrypting personal files (which will ultimately be backed up to the cloud) and have been doing my best to follow best practices.

There are many forms of authenticated encryption. (AES-GCM, AES-SIV, AES-GCM-SIV, CBC + HMAC, CTR + HMAC, etc.) However, I'm having a hard time determining which of these modes-of-operation suits my use-case best. Speaking broadly:

I've heard many times that "GCM is harder to get right" due to the serious risks associated with nonce reuse as well as its predisposition to side-channel attacks if implemented poorly. Although it *is* fast.

I know AES-SIV is at least utilized by Cryptomator, a tool similar to what I'm trying to develop, ([per their architecture docs](https://docs.cryptomator.org/en/latest/security/architecture/#filename-encryption)). AES-SIV has a smaller penalty for nonce reuse compared to GCM but perhaps isn't as fast.

AES-GCM-SIV attempts to combine the positives of both GCM and SIV by being both fast and somewhat resistant to nonce reuse.

As far as CBC + HMAC is concerned, HMAC leverages 256-bit authentication tags over GHASH's weaker 128-bit authentication tags (used by GCM). However, CBC cannot be parallelized in the same way GCM can.

CTR + HMAC *can* be parallelized in a way similar to GCM but with stronger authentication tags. (Again, HMAC using 256-bit authentication tags over GHASH's 128-bit authentication tags)

Despite the reading I've done so far, I haven't been able to determine why one might choose one of these methods over the other. At the end of the day, I would really just like to secure my files safely in the cloud with at least some assurance that the files I encrypt are authentic and have not been tampered with or corrupted in any way.

I would really appreciate any help that could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I would do ctr+hmac(blake2) for backup

Comment: @RichieFrame Why CTR and HMAC-BLAKE2 instead of, say, ChaCha20-Poly1305?

Comment: @meci: Based on *GCM is harder to get right* I suppose you are going to *implement by yourself* one of these algorithms. I would discourage you from doing that. Or you are going to use some library and you are not sure if the authors have implemented it correctly?

Comment: I think you've already got a pretty good overview of different modes, in the end you will have to make your own decision, not us. Personally I think this question is opinionated as such. I'd focus on the amount of data / files that can be encrypted using a key (or keys) for such purposes (next to performance, of course).

Comment: @mentallurg I would certainly prefer to use _somebody else's_ implementation if I can find a solid/trusted implementation of whatever scheme I choose. My concern with GCM is that perhaps, due to its complexities, it is more prone to poor implementation than the others.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica I was really looking to understand why someone might choose one of these methods over the other, not necessarily "which method is best." Clearly each of these methods have their own pros and cons but at a high level I haven't seen anyone explain the kinds of jobs these schemes are typically used for. Is GCM a more all-purpose form of AE over SIV which is more specifically geared towards ____? However, I'm beginning to see that might be asking too much. The answer is probably more nuanced than that.

Comment: Well, maybe it is possible to build a table with e.g. relative speed, maximum amount of bytes, flexibility, robustness etc. for all these modes. Might be quite a bit of work though, you often see these kind of comparisons in papers by academics that cannot come up with anything more original.

Comment: @forest blake2 is very fast, just like poly1305, but will provide a 512-bit hash, and this single function can then also be used for integrity verification and deduplication in a single operation during encryption and authentication with performance exceeding the read speed of the disk if there are multiple cores

Comment: @meci: To *somewhat resistant to nonce reuse*: Why are you concerned about nonce reuse in *your* specific use case? You are going to encrypt your *personal files* (not for bank transactions or similar). Reused nonce could help to restore authentication key and to potentially to replace some block in your file without you noticing that. But this costs much efforts for an attacker and should have sense for him. If forging the file makes your bank to transfer 1 000 000 instead of 1 000, then it can make sense. But why would hacker want to forge your *private files*?

Comment: Evaluate the risks in *your* specific case. Then may be you come to conclusion that even AES-GCM without any HMAC is quite sufficient for *your* case. Then you will have multiple candidates. I find that actually all you listed are fine for *your* case. Now think of other criteria like platform (Java, C#, C++, ...), available libraries, community and level of support, bug fixing practices in that community, complexity of the API (for *you* as a new user), performance of the code.

Answer (score 5):

I went through this decision process in 2018 and ended up going with something *very* conservative: **encrypt-then-MAC with AES-256-CBC and HMAC-SHA-512 truncated to 256 bits.**

- Why SHA-512 over SHA-256?  SHA-512 is faster on 64-bit machines.  (Though recent AMD processors' SHA-256 instructions yield a 4x speed-up: [link](https://www.lasca.ic.unicamp.br/media/publications/p9-faz-hernandez.pdf#page=11)).
- Why AES-256 over AES-128?  https://blog.1password.com/guess-why-were-moving-to-256-bit-aes-keys/

This was fast enough for my use cases, but is much slower than many of the alternatives.  The AES part is fast on Intel processors; hashing ends up taking ~80% of the time on long messages.

**Alternatives worth considering today:**

Replace HMAC-SHA-512 with keyed BLAKE3 (~2.5x faster for long messages).  BLAKE3 itself is very new, but has a somewhat mature lineage.

XChaCha20-Poly1305 (~2x faster for long messages).  Nonces can be up to 192 bits, so there's less of a risk of collisions.

AES-GCM-SIV (~5x faster for long messages).  Doesn't seem to be widely implemented yet.

**Note**: These performance estimates are vaguely based on a "typical" 2016 x86-64 processor, which has dedicated AES instructions and some general-purpose SIMD, e.g. AVX.

Answer (score 2):

In cryptographic operation modes that require the initialization vector to be non-repeated rather than random, the initialization vector is called "nonce" (**n**umber used **once**).

Do not design the implementation of a mode if you cannot fulfill the requirements of the mode. For example, if a mode depends on a uniqueness of the initialization vector, you have to do all your best to ensure the uniqueness. If you cannot guarantee the uniqueness, choose another mode that does not have such a requirement. Otherwise, you may have false sense of security and your application may eventually end up in being used in such a scenario that ignorance of the basic requirement will lead to failure. There are many examples when cutting the corners ultimately lead to failure. For example [even occasional use of the same one-time pads by different senders in the 1940s allowed the adversary to decrypt the messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venona_project). Although it has been known that such reuse is a serious weakness, people probably thought that cutting the corners would not have consequences, but it had.

So, rather than trying to find the modes that are "somewhat resistant to nonce reuse", ensure that your implementation does all its best to prevent nonce reuse, or find another mode that does not depend on nonce. The problem of ensuring the uniqueness of the nonce is a matter of a separate discussion, but it is practically achievable even in your scenario.
Since your scenario does not allow timing attacks or padding oracle attacks, you may use AES-CBC with any MAC, like two-pass HMAC with SHA-2 or one-pass HMAC with SHA-3 in any order, like Encrypt-then-MAC (EtM), Encrypt-and-MAC (E&M), MAC-then-Encrypt (MtE). if you don’t need higher speed and parallelism. Otherwise, use AES-GCM AEAD. However, since the CBC mode give you many options with HMAC, I would have followed the KISS (keep it simple) principle, to be less inventive, and have just implemented the AES-GCM AEAD.